# vlc issues with Monkey's Audio .ape files

Tags: vlc

I'm Running 13.04. When I try to play .ape files in vlc, for some reason it plays only a split second then quiets repeatedly.

This a screen shot of the output when run from terminal. It keeps saying
buffer way too late
nothing to play 
...
nothing to play
buffer too late

On this machine, other media players play vlc fine.

on the same machine, in another installation, vlc in 12.10 plays ape with no issues but all other media players struggle with what I have now.

please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

solved this problem by removing vlc and installing it from vlc repos.

```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
     sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install vlc
```